# Como puedo modificar los permisos por defecto en linux?

Tags: linux, permisos

Concretamente estoy utilizando raspbian, una versión basada en debian optimizada para Raspberry Pi. Me gustaría modificar los permisos que se les da a los ficheros nuevos por defecto, he buscado información y lo que quiero hacer se puede hacer mediante el comando "umask".

El problema es que no sé donde modificar este parámetro en mi sistema, he leído que para que afecte a todos los usuarios y no sólo hasta que se mantenga la sesión de consola encendida, hay que modificar el .bashrc que se encuentra en mi home; y no se como acceder a este.

¿Puede ser que no exista en mi versión de linux? O estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: pacomoral: Mencionas que "has leído". Para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad, me parece que deberías incluir el enlace a la fuente que consultaste, así como si has buscado una pregunta similar en el sitio, indiques si la encontraste o no y si la encontraste que indiques si algo de la misma te sirvió o no.

Answer (score 2):

Asegurate que estas usando bash. Si editar .bashrc no te sirve, puedes cambiar la umask por defecto en `/etc/profile`. Aparte de eso tienes los hechos al revés. El cambio en .bashrc en la carpeta home afecta el usuario, no el sistema. Las configuraciónes globales encuentras en `/etc`.

Si se trata de la umask para bash y quieres cambiar el valor por defecto, revisa:

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
/etc/skel/.bashrc
```

en `/etc/skel/` encuentras las pautas del sistema para las configuraciones de nuevos usuarios, el otro es la configuración global de bash. Si no lo encuentras precisamente en esta ruta (desconozco que variante de linux usas en el PI) podrías usarlos usando `find / | grep bashrc`.

Si tu distribución es más reciente, es posible que tu umask por defecto esta manejado por pam, en este caso la configuración se debe encontrar en `/etc/login.defs`.

Tipicamente vas a encontrar una entrada como:

```
UMASK        022
```

Eso significa que nuevas archivos se crean con mod 755. (la umask se puede calcular segun 777 - el mod que buscas. Así si quieres crear con mod 750, usas un umask de 027).

Answer (score 0):

Los ficheros profile están en /etc/profile /etc/profile.d /etc/bashrc /etc/login

Una vez cambiados, no te olvides de modificar también los ficheros que están en /etc/skel, que son los que se copian al crear un usuario nuevo.